# svn library FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2]

Tags: svn, subprocess, remote-server

I try to use svn library on a distant server and for the moment I follow simple examples. In this case I try to connect on my server and obtain some informations. Connexion seems to work but when I start to ask for inforamtion I have an error message like:
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] Le fichier spécifié est introuvable
Previous messages speak about subprocess.py, common.py and common_base.py

I have found some discussions about [WinError 2] but I don't understand what do they mean and what I have to investigate to solve it.

Here you can find my simple code without private informations:

```
import svn.remote

initial_path = 'http://svnServer'
r = svn.remote.RemoteClient(initial_path,  username="user", password="user")
info = r.info()
print(info)
```

If somebody could help me it will be really nice.

Regards,

Comment: Could you send, the exact error you received ? also, first thing to check: is svn installed and working well in your system when called directly from shell ?

Comment: I have solved it so it is not necessary but thank you for your help & time :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in the README, you need to install the CLI client for svn:

> The library wraps the svn commandline client, which should consequently be installed on the local system.

You can then either:

- Make sure this executable is in a directory listed in your PATH environment variable
- Specify the path to this executable in the 'svn_filepath' argument of your RemoteClient constructor (https://github.com/dsoprea/PySvn/blob/master/svn/common.py)

Hope that helps

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your answer.

I finally solve my problem and your answer helped me a lot.
When I was looking on my SVN installation I didn't find "svn" file so I re-launch SVN installation on windows. SVN on command line was not crossed and it was for this reason that my simple example was not working.

Have a good day!